# can we draw a line between two different canvas windows

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rq7L.png)

i want draw a line between two different canvas.
 In above image the two different rectangle represent two canvas.
I want to join both rectangle two each other can it is possible.

html code is below

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <canvas style="z-index:1" id="canvas" width="200" height="600"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <canvas style="z-index:1" id="canvas1" width="200" height="600"></canvas>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `<hr style="border: 2px solid gold;width:800px">` Now adjust location using absolute positioning also color and length

Comment: Or create a third canvas with transparent background, and draw the lines to that canvas.